# Get smallest and biggest number from Console.WriteLine()

Tags: c#, string, parsing

"Exercise Guidelines:
First **read the count** of numbers, for example in a variable n. Then **consequently enter n numbers** with one **for** loop. While entering each new number, save in two variables the **smallest** and the **largest** number until this moment.(...)"

I do an exercise from C# tutorial and I have problem with extracting numbers from one line string consisting of unknown number of numbers.
I have such code so far:

```
Console.WriteLine("Type in several Integers:");
string input = System.Console.ReadLine();
string[] splittedLine = input.Split(' ');

foreach(string number in splittedLine)
{
    Console.Write(" " + number);
}

Console.Read();
```

I am supposed to print smallest and biggest number from input using for loop.
As far as I understand I need to parse numbers from `splitedLine` array so they are integers, then compare them and use `Int32.MaxValue` and `Int32.MinValue`. 
I'm stuck on "Parsing" part of the code.

---------- update -----------

When I add

```
int[] parsedNumbers = int.Parse(splittedLine[])
```

I get error that splittedLine[] needs a value. Is it possible to bulk-parse all elements from array?

Comment: Look at the `int.Parse` method.

Comment: check my edit please.

Comment: You could use `Linq` or an for loop.

Comment: you mean to use for loop to int.Parse array elements?

Comment: you have a `foreach` loop there already - why don't you do the parsing of each element in the loop?

Comment: because I don't know how many elements are provided

Comment: @paddy , see my answer below. If anything's not understood, I'll explain it. I did it the in the most KISS (keep it simple stupid), newb-friendly way I could

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most basic solution (no linq or anything) based on your code:

```
Console.WriteLine("Type in several Integers:");
string input = System.Console.ReadLine();
string[] splittedLine = input.Split(' ');

int max = Int32.MinValue; // initialize the maximum number to the minimum possible values
int min = Int32.MaxValue;  // initialize the minimum number to the maximum possible value
foreach(string number in splittedLine)
{
    int currentNumber = int.Parse(number); // convert the current string element 
                                           // to an integer so we can do comparisons

    if(currentNumber > max)  // Check if it's greater than the last max number
       max = currentNumber;  // if so, the maximum is the current number

    if(currentNumber < min)  // Check if it's lower than the last min number
       min = currentNumber;  // if so, the minium is the current number
}
Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Minimum: {0} Maximum: {1}", min, max));
```

No error checking done here, so the input must be correct

Comment: That works. And it is in deed simplest way to do it I guess as LINQ is not being used and Int32.MinValue and Int32.MaxValue are used instead.

Comment: Indeed... Linq just makes everything easier (or you could use `Math.Max` and `Math.Min` instead of `if`'s), I just wanted to make very basic code. Error checking should be definitely done to this (using `TryParse` instead of `Parse`, and checking the console entry), but I'm sticking to what you asked and giving the most basic possible solution since you seem to be learning and following tutorials: probably error checking and `TryXXX` methods will come later :-)

Comment: I can allow this since it is clearly stated to insert integers only and I don't need to worry about identifying ints.

Comment: I want to avoid easing the coding with what's coming in future chapters of tutorial. Thanks @Jcl

Comment: @paddy once you understand the basics, it's easy to go from there... remember to mark as accepted the answer that you think does a better job to you personally, all answers given are perfectly valid and you can probably learn some tips from each

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
int test;
var numbers = 
   from n in input.Split(' ')
   where int.TryParse(n, out test) // Only to test if n is an integer
   select int.Parse(n)
;

int maxValue = numbers.Max();
int minValue = numbers.Min();
```

Without `Linq`

```
int maxValue = int.MinValue;
int minValue = int.MaxValue;

foreach(var s in input.Split(' '))
{
    int number;
    if(int.TryParse(s, out number))
    {
        maxValue = Math.Max(maxValue, number);
        minValue = Math.Min(minValue, number);
    }
}
```

Comment: The tutorial which I'm following has not arrived to the point that explains your solution yet. I would prefer to stick to the basic stuff the chapter is covering. Any chance to combine it with for loop?

Comment: what is the List here for?

Comment: I mean, is it possible to substitute it with something like array? the tutorial didn't cover the List so far, that's why I'm asking..

Comment: @paddy You can use the method `ToArray()` to make an array ;)

Comment: You don't actually need `ToArray()` - any `IEnumerable` supports min and max

Comment: @BrokenGlass Thx. I removed it.

Comment: ok, wait. I don't know if I understand this piece of code. I don't need to store input.Split() anywhere as I did, but go for foreach straight away to parse each element of splitted input and at the same time store them in numbers. then I can look for my Max and Min values in numbers. Is that correct?

Comment: @paddy Yes. That's the intension

Comment: `IEnumerable`'s `Max` and `Min` are linq extensions (they live in `System.Linq`), so your "no linq" code does contain linq

Comment: It definitely is ugly, but hey :-)

Comment: @Matthias Your answer is not exactly what tutorial wanted me to do(way of solving problem) but I understand it best of all answers. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

To get min and max values of user input you can use LINQ.

Sample code:

```
Console.WriteLine("Type in several Integers:");
string input = System.Console.ReadLine();
List<int> numbers = null;
if(!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(input)) // Check if any character has been entered by user
{
    string[] splittedLine = input.Split(' '); // Split entered string
    if(splittedLine != null && splittedLine.Length != 0) // Check if array is not null and has at least one element
    {
        foreach (var item in splittedLine)
        {
            int tmpNumber;
            if(int.TryParse(item, out tmpNumber)) // Parse string to integer with check
            {
                if (numbers == null) numbers = new List<int>(); // If is at least one integer - create list with numbers
                numbers.Add(tmpNumber); // Add number to list of int
            }                            
        }
    }
}
else
{
    // TODO: info for user
}

if(numbers != null) // Check if list of int is not null
{
    Console.WriteLine("Min: {0}", numbers.Min()); // Get min value from numbers using LINQ
    Console.WriteLine("Max: {0}", numbers.Max()); // Get max value from numbers using LINQ
}
else
{
    // TODO: info for user
}
Console.Read();
```

Min and Max value without using LINQ:

```
...
if(numbers != null)
{
    var min = numbers[0];
    var max = numbers[0];
    foreach (var item in numbers)
    {
        if (item < min) min = item;
        if (item > max) max = item;
    }
    Console.WriteLine("Min: {0}", min);
    Console.WriteLine("Max: {0}", max);
}
...
```

Comment: the tutorial doesn't cover Linq so far.

Comment: @paddy I have added some comments to sample code. LINQ is the simplest way to get min and max numbers. If you don't want to use it, you can create `foreach` loop and compare all values to get min and max.

Comment: @paddy check my answer again. I have added sample code to get min and max values withoud LINQ.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Program
{
    static public void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Get input
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter numbers seperated by spaces");
        string input = Console.ReadLine();
        string[] splittedInput = input.Split(' ');

        // Insure numbers are actually inserted
        while (splittedInput.Length <= 0) 
        {
            Console.WriteLine("No numbers inserted. Please enter numbers seperated by spaces");
            splittedInput = input.Split(' ');
        }

        // Try and parse the strings to integers
        // Possible exceptions : ArgumentNullException, FormatException, OverflowException
        // ArgumentNullException shouldn't happen because we ensured we have input and the strings can not be empty
        // FormatException can happen if someone inserts a string that is not in the right format for an integer,
        //      Which is : {0,1}[+\-]{1,}[0-9]
        // OverflowException happens if the integer inserted is either smaller than the lowest possible int
        //      or bigger than the largest possible int
        // We keep the 'i' variable outside for nice error messages, so we can easily understand
        // What number failed to parse
        int[] numbers = new int[splittedInput.Length];
        int i = 0;
        try
        {
            for (; i < numbers.Length; ++i)
            {
                numbers[i] = int.Parse(splittedInput[i]);
            }
        }
        catch (FormatException)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Failed to parse " + splittedInput[i] + " to an integer");
            return;
        }
        catch (OverflowException)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(splittedInput[i] + " is either bigger the the biggest integer possible (" +
                int.MaxValue + ") or smaller then the lowest integer possible (" + int.MinValue);
            return;
        }

        // Save min and max values as first number
        int minValue = numbers[0], maxValue = numbers[0];

        // Simple logic from here - number lower than min? min becomes numbers, and likewise for max
        for (int index = 1; index < numbers.Length; ++i)
        {
            int currentNumber = numbers[index];
            minValue = minValue > currentNumber ? currentNumber : minValue;
            maxValue = maxValue < currentNumber ? currentNumber : maxValue;
        }

        // Show output
        Console.WriteLine("Max value is : " + maxValue);
        Console.WriteLine("Min value is : " + minValue);
    }
}
```

This is the most accurate, non-linq and extensive answer I could write on Notepad++